# How to remove class from shared layout on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a shared layout like so,

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="mb-3"></nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

In a page that uses the shared layout how can I remove mb-3? Set it to mb-0? Or override it? I don't want there to be a margin-bottom.

I've tried to remove it with JavaScript on load but there's a delay and you can see the page jump.

I've also tried to set something like the following, but there's no change.

```
    body > header > nav {
        margin-bottom: -30px !important;
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can force it by overwriting the actual class, instead of adding another style (not tested):

```
body > header > nav.mb-3 { /* added .mb-3 */
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to remove class:

```
const element = document.querySelector("nav");
element.classList.remove("mb-3");
```

Comment: Originally, I had this code under window.onload and it would cause a delay (you could see the class being removed), though if I just write it as it is on it's own then there's no delay.